# How to document C macros with Doxygen

Tags: c, macros, doxygen

I am working on a problem in C that requires more than a few function macros.  I would like to document the functions in Doxygen, but Doxygen is not recognizing the function macros.  I am positing a simple example problem below and am wondering if anyone can give me some guidance on how to write the doc strings.

```
/**
/* \def TYPE##_GENERIC_MAX(type x, type y)
   \param x A random variable
   \param y a random variable
   \return z Another random variable
 */
#define TYPE##_GENERIC_MAX(type)         \
type type##_max(type x, type y)   \
{                                 \
    return x > y ? x : y;         \
}
```

When I try to document this with Doxygen I get the following error:

```
warning: documentation for unknown define TYPE##_GENERIC_MAX found.
```

Comment: The macro definition is bogus — the macro name cannot contain `##`.  You could write `#define TYPE_GENERIC_MAX(type) …` and then use `TYPE_GENERIC_TYPE(int)` to define the function and invoke `int_max(expr1, expr2)` to determine the maximum of the two expressions.  You might add `static inline` at the start of the function definition too; that would avoid multiple definitions of the function.

Comment: As a matter of idle fact, the macro shown attempts to define an object-like macro `TYPE` but the body of the macro starts `##` which is not valid; it must separate two identifier fragments in the expansion of a function-like macro.  See the constraint in [§6.10.3.3 The `##` operator ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.3): _A `##` preprocessing token shall not occur at the beginning or at the end of a replacement list for either form of macro definition._

Comment: If you fix the `#define` syntax and still have problems with documentation, then you probably have a valid question.

Comment: Also note that you have `/**` and in the next line `/*`, the second slipped probably in. Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That was a type when I wrote the question and will fix it.  It is not defined that way in my actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a small test with the current doxygen version (1.9.4).

I used the following setting:

```
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
```

and the source code:

```
/**
   \def TYPE_GENERIC_MAX(type)
   \param type the type
 */
#define TYPE_GENERIC_MAX(type)    \
/** \
   \param x A random variable \
   \param y a random variable \
   \return z Another random variable \
 */ type type##_max(type x, type y)   \
{                                 \
    return x > y ? x : y;         \
}

TYPE_GENERIC_MAX(int)
```

and got as result:

[image]

Comment: I think I see where the problem is.  I do not declare the `TYPE_GENERIC_MAX(int)`, in my .h file and leave that to the user in their main program.  as a result it only documents the `#def` statement and not the functions.